# Show infinite primes of the form $12k + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Show that there are infinite amount of primes of the form $12k + 1$ for $k \in \Bbb{N}$.

I tried to use similar techniques I have seen to prove that there are infinite prime for primes of the form $4k + 3$.

The technique was assume that there are finite number of that form $p_1$ to $p_n$ and get a contradiction by considering the number $$4\left(\prod_i^n p_i\right) + 3$$but couldn't apply the same methods in this case.

Comment: The sequence $a_k=12k+1$ contains an infinite amount of prime numbers, since $12$ and $1$ are coprime integers (according to [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)).

Comment: There are several obstacles to trying to use the old familiar Euclidean method to primes of this form. It might help you, maybe just in this particular case, to see it as a matter of construction rather than contradiction. That is, if we have a finite list of primes of this form, how do we use that list to obtain another prime of that form to add to our list? Trouble is, the potential new prime might actually be the product of primes of the form $12k + 5$, $12k + 7$ and/or $12k + 11$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Consider the polynomial $x^4-x^2+1$.

> If there were finitely many, let $x$ be their product and consider a prime divisor $p$ ($\neq2,3$) of $x^4-x^2+1$. Then $x^6\equiv-1\pmod p$, so $p\equiv1\pmod4$, and $(2x^2-1)^2\equiv-3\pmod p$, so $-3$ and thus $3$ is a square mod $p$, so $p$ is a square mod $3$ by QR, so $p\equiv1\pmod3$. Contradiction.

More generally, the prime divisors of $\Phi_n(x)$ ($n$th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)) for $x\in\mathbb Z$ are either prime divisors of $n$ or $\equiv1\pmod n$.